# How to set node position in NetAnim? I always get Use SetConstantPosition if it is stationary error

Tags: ns-3

I am new to ns-3. I am trying to understand from the very basic. I created a network simulation containing two switches, then I want to visualize it using NetAnim.

Followings are my code

```
/* -*- Mode:C++; c-file-style:"gnu"; indent-tabs-mode:nil; -*- */
/*
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation;
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/yans-wifi-helper.h"
#include "ns3/ssid.h"
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("HMTMRSim");

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  std::cout << "create switches" << std::endl;
  NodeContainer switches;
  switches.Create(2); // create two switches

  AnimationInterface anim("myanim.xml");

  std::cout << "set position for switches" << std::endl;

  anim.SetConstantPosition(switches.Get(0), 48.0, 70.0, 0);
  anim.SetConstantPosition(switches.Get(1), 48.0, 90.0, 0);

  anim.UpdateNodeDescription(0, "Main");
  anim.UpdateNodeDescription(1, "Rack0");

  anim.UpdateNodeSize(0, 10, 10);
  anim.UpdateNodeColor(0, 0, 0, 255);
  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it works without problem, but I get this warning

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/arwankhoiruddin/Downloads/ns-allinone-3.30.1/ns-3.30.1/build'
Build commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (18.508s)
create switches
AnimationInterface WARNING:Node:0 Does not have a mobility model. Use SetConstantPosition if it is stationary
AnimationInterface WARNING:Node:1 Does not have a mobility model. Use SetConstantPosition if it is stationary
AnimationInterface WARNING:Node:0 Does not have a mobility model. Use SetConstantPosition if it is stationary
AnimationInterface WARNING:Node:
```

When I open in NetAnim (shown in the picture below), it seems to ignore the position that I defined in my code. As you see in the following properties, the first node (node 0) has position of (x,y) = (81.00, 83.00).

I am aware that I can change the position by changing the value in properties, but later using ns-3, I want to create quite a complex network, so it will be difficult to set them manually.

In internet, I found this suggestion, i.e. adding mobility to replace the SetConstantPosition. However, the result in NetAnim is still similar.

```
MobilityHelper mobility;
Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAlloc = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator>();
positionAlloc->Add(Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
positionAlloc->Add(Vector(5.0, 0.0, 0.0));
mobility.SetPositionAllocator(positionAlloc);
mobility.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
mobility.Install(switches);
```

Please let me know how to set the position from my code and get rid of the warning.

Thank you for your kind helps

[image: netanim]

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question in NS3 Google Group. Few days later, I got a great answer from Liu XinXin (many thanks for the help - her StackOverflow account is xxliu95). Here's the code that she posted

```
int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "create switches" << std::endl;
  NodeContainer switches;
  switches.Create(2); // create two switches

  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
  mobility.Install (switches);

  AnimationInterface anim("myanim.xml");

  std::cout << "set position for switches" << std::endl;

  Ptr<ConstantPositionMobilityModel> s1 = switches.Get (0)->GetObject<ConstantPositionMobilityModel> ();
  Ptr<ConstantPositionMobilityModel> s2 = switches.Get (1)->GetObject<ConstantPositionMobilityModel> ();

  s1->SetPosition (Vector ( 48.0, 70.0, 0  ));
  s2->SetPosition (Vector ( 48.0, 90.0, 0  ));

  anim.UpdateNodeDescription(0, "Main");
  anim.UpdateNodeDescription(1, "Rack0");

  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

This is what I got in NetAnim

[image: NetAnim XML Picture]